# How to point a subdomain to point to a GCP Click to Deploy VM on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

We wanted a subdomain http://magento.ngstorefront.com to point to a VM on Google Cloud. We could not find clear docs on this.

What we did:

1. Deployed a [Magento Google Click to Deploy](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/partners/click-to-deploy-images?project=spartan-card-232819) VM from marketplace
2. Assigned a Static ip address to the VM --> 35.193.85.53
3. The default Magento site loads at http://35.193.85.53
   [image]
4. To have the sub-domain http://magento.ngstorefront.com load the site (loading at http://35.193.85.53). So we added a new A record for "magento.ngstorefront.com --> 35.193.85.53" in Google Cloud DNS
   [image]
5. On the domain registrar (Google Domains), we added a **Registered host** (magento.ngstorefront.com) and a **Custom Record** as below.
   [image]

   [image]

But the site doesn't load at http://magento.ngstorefront.com What are we missing?

Comment: When you configure DNS settings for a new record it can take a few minutes before the record is available. If you change an existing record you often have to wait at least the TTL time. In your case I think you did not wait long enough.

Answer (score 1):

The subdomain is resolving now. Wanted to add the answer.

The mistake we did was to create the subdomain A record in Registrar (Google Domains). Although registered in GoogleDomains, our primary domain **ngstorefront.com** is pointing to **Siteground**

[image]

So we have to add the A record in **Siteground** instead of **GoogleDomains** , like this

[image]

Updated on 3/15/2019

While the above solved the issue of IP address pointing and loading Magento, but we had one issue where the URL would change to IP instead of staying as  http://magento.ngstorefront.com

To solve the above, do this:
Login to Magento Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs

And enter the domain name you want Magento to use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the answer provided, I'd say that the problem is, still having set `siteground.us` as `NS`.

You'd have to change the `NS` records to Cloud DNS name-servers at Google Domains, then it would resolve through Cloud DNS and the zone-file can be maintained there (as you've tried without effect).